# Google Data Studio Conditional Formatting via User Provided Parameter

Tags: parameters, conditional-formatting, looker-studio

Seeking some ideas from the expert community.  I have a report with confidential metrics tied to a variety of individuals.  This is a basic row-by-row report with each individual and their metrics represented by one row.

To confidentially display each person's relative performance without them seeing their peers' data, I would like to have every row use a black font on a black background.  Then, when the report owner types in the last name of an individual, I want GDS to turn that particular line's fonts white to reveal the scores associated with the individual of interest.

I thought I was onto something when I tried to create a user-input control parameter with a fixed list of individuals' names - making it an easy drop down selection.  Everything worked great up to that point; however, when I created the conditional formatting rule, it will not allow me to use the control variable (represented by an "@" in front of the variable name) within the rule "syntax".

Am I out of luck trying to use this type of input variable to help control the formatting of my screen.  Any hints or tips to make this work would be greatly appreciated.  Or, if you have an idea of how to solve my original challenge of revealing information about one individual WITHOUHT collapsing all rows to feature JUST that individual (so I can retain some ranking stature), please chime in.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Good news.  I was able to make my original plan of attack work.  Originally, I didn't recognize the ability to select the control parameter variable from a list (the right-most comparison variable).  See the attached image.

[image]

At the end of the day, it works.